# How can I modify attachfile icon?

Tags: moderncv, attachfile, clip, icon

I'm working on an moderncv and trying to edit the default attachfile icon (Pushpin) to use the Paperclip, but it returns an error.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,spanish,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[unicode]{attachfile}

\firstname{Peter} % Your first name
\familyname{Peter Peter} % Your last name

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
%ATTACHFILE: pdf-generating mode 
\RequirePackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
\else
    \PackageWarningNoLine{attachfile}{%
        attachfile works _only_ with pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX\MessageBreak
        and _only_ in PDF-generating mode. For this run,\MessageBreak
        placeholders will be substituted for all\MessageBreak
        attachfile commands%
}
\fi

%ATTACHFILE: packages required
\RequirePackage{keyval}
\RequirePackage{calc}
\RequirePackage{color}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------



\begin{document}

%Recreate Adobe Acrobat’s Paperclip icon
\newcommand{\atfi@acroPaperclip@data}{%
    q 0.75 G 0 i 2.5 w 1 J 4 M 1.9619 11.7559 m 1.9619 3.3037
    1.9619 2.5059 v 1.9619 1.707 4.0947 1.25 y 7.4141 1.25 l 9.4292
    1.8223 9.4292 3.3066 v 9.4292 4.79 9.4292 16.8945 y 9.7852
    18.1514 8.481 18.1514 v 7.1768 18.1514 5.1616 18.1514 y 3.8574
    17.9209 3.8574 16.8945 v 3.8574 15.8652 3.8574 6.6172 y 4.3325
    5.418 5.1025 5.418 v 5.8726 5.418 6.5845 5.418 y 7.6812 5.6455
    7.6812 6.4736 v 7.6812 7.3027 7.6812 11.5264 y S 0 G 1.2495
    12.4404 m 1.2495 3.9883 1.2495 3.1895 v 1.2495 2.3906 3.3833
    1.9326 y 6.7026 1.9326 l 8.7178 2.5068 8.7178 3.9902 v 8.7178
    5.4736 8.7178 17.5781 y 9.0732 18.834 7.769 18.834 v 6.4653
    18.834 4.4497 18.834 y 3.146 18.6055 3.146 17.5781 v 3.146
    16.5498 3.146 7.3018 y 3.6201 6.1016 4.3911 6.1016 v 5.1611
    6.1016 5.873 6.1016 y 6.9692 6.3301 6.9692 7.1572 v 6.9692
    7.9863 6.9692 12.21 y S \atfi@color@rgb\space RG 1 w
    1.2495 12.4404 m 1.2495 3.9883 1.2495 3.1895 v 1.2495 2.3906
    3.3833 1.9326 y 6.7026 1.9326 l 8.7178 2.5068 8.7178 3.9902 v
    8.7178 5.4736 8.7178 17.5781 y 9.0732 18.834 7.769 18.834 v
    6.4653 18.834 4.4497 18.834 y 3.146 18.6055 3.146 17.5781 v
    3.146 16.5498 3.146 7.3018 y 3.6201 6.1016 4.3911 6.1016 v
    5.1611 6.1016 5.873 6.1016 y 6.9692 6.3301 6.9692 7.1572 v
    6.9692 7.9863 6.9692 12.21 y S Q
}

%Draw \atfi@acroPaperclip@data in a box of the appropriate size
\DeclareRobustCommand{\atfi@acroPaperclip}{%
    \raisebox{-1.25bp}{\parbox[b][21bp]{12bp}{%
        \rule{0pt}{0pt}\pdfliteral{\atfi@acroPaperclip@data}}%  
    }%
}
```

The ERROR:

! Missing number, treated as zero.

a
l.55 }
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up`weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you think that you need to recreate something, the paperclip works by default:

```
\documentclass[11pt,spanish,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[unicode]{attachfile}

\firstname{Peter} % Your first name
\familyname{Peter Peter} % Your last name

\begin{document}
\attachfile[icon=Paperclip]{article.cls}
article.cls

\end{document}
```

[image]